# Keras model.predict giving different shape from training label array

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the following code to try and learn tensorflow. I've clearly specified the shapes of the training and validation `X` and `y` arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

f = lambda x: 2*x
Xtrain = np.random.rand(400,1)
ytrain = f(Xtrain)
Xval = np.random.rand(200,1)
yval = f(Xval)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
             )

model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=50, verbose=0)
```

When I run `yval.shape, model.predict(Xval).shape`, I get the output `((200, 1), (200, 10))`. I'm not able to understand where these extra 9 dimensions are coming from. Even the `Xval` prediction should have the shape `(200, 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10 outputs came from the fact that you have **10 neurons in the final layer** of your network.

If you change your model to

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
])
```

its output will have a shape of `(200, 1)`.

Comment: Thank you! Another thing - when I re-run this code, `model.predict(Xval)` gives an all-zero array. What am I missing?

Comment: I just ran the code and it outputs non-zero values... Maybe you substituted an array with `np.zeros()` ?

Comment: Nope, no substitution. The code starting from `Xtrain` till the end is in a single Jupyter cell. When I run it the first time, the prediction is fine. But if I re-run, it gives all zeroes. Then I run for for a couple of times - again all zeroes. And after a few retries it gives a proper prediction again. Even if I put the randomized part in a prior cell, and run the code AFTER that in a separate cell repeatedly, the same thing happens. Something's off (I've changed the layer structure as you prescribed)

Comment: Neural Networks are stochastic to a large degree. Maybe for some weight initializations the model outputs only zeros... I'm not sure.

Comment: I looked it up - turns out it may be due to the relu activation function. It can be replaced by tanh or leaky relu